# Is there any publicly available algorithms for Neurofeedback using EEG?

Tags: eeg, biofeedback

How do these software work? Is there a clear algorithm I can follow to make one by myself?

I can make software for Mac, Web and Mobile. I also have two EEG headsets: Emotiv Epoc and Neurosky MindWave Mobile. I can connect with these, record EEG and so on using Python and Objective C. But I cannot find out how a Neurofeedback software decides when and what to modify in an audio or video play back to train the brain.

Comment: what neurofeedback are you trying to implement?  what's the goal?

Comment: Two areas of interest:
1) Increase attention / focus. (For students in our training centers)
2) Reduce anxiety (For some of our adult customers especially executives)

Comment: like if you're doing it for fun then all the power to you.  but selling something that is not proven to work, and may be harmful, is borderline unethical/exploitative

Comment: We are planning on offering them for free, not for a price. Because like you said, we don't know how many will find it beneficial and also if we can measure the improvements.

Back to the original question: how do these software work? Example: http://www.mindreflector.com/ They claim to be beneficial for your brain. Why did you say these are not proven to work and may be harmful?

I like to know where companies like Mindreflector get the algorithms.